# How to connect sql server via IP Public

Tags: sql-server

I want to get connection to other sql server,
but the things that I get are only, IP Public of the database server.

how to make my local sqlserver mngment studio direct connect to connect to db server by IP Public,
the thing that i've done

- able all tcp/ip in configuration manager
- make firewall off
- I can ping that IP public from server

please help me, what the way to do connect sql server by piblic IP, I want to try connect by sqlserver mngmnt studio with
*IP address,1433*.
Could everyone show me the step by step I must to do?

Comment: Are you looking for Microsoft SQL Server connection strings? https://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server/

Comment: If you cannot ping that IP address, you cannot connect to any server instance running on it? So - can you ping it sucessfully? How do you know the IP address and port? Did you ask someone or was it given to you? Is it something you installed yourself?

Comment: @SMor yes, in server can ping that IP with port 1433

Comment: @Tony, yes at the end I need the connection string, but firstly I wnt to make sure, it purely connect in sqlserver managemnt studio

Comment: If you changed the TCP/IP settings in SQL Server Configuration Manager - did you stop and start the SQL Server service for the changes to take effect?